# Python Recursive Spiral List Printing

Tags: python, recursion

so I'm looking to use a function to take a list and first print each item on a line in order and then print the items backwards using recursion and no loops.

a list of `[1, 2, 3]` input to the function would return

```
1
2
3
2
1
```

Can anybody give me a hand?

Comment: This sounds like homework. It's generally a better idea to post your (broken) code and let us help you fix it, than asking for the complete code without any proof that you've even tried to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: yeah I thought it might be perceived that way, but it's actually a question that was on my final a month ago and has just been nagging me (trying to enjoy my winter break now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without generating any intermediate list; the trick here is to do the second print after returning from the recursive call (except for the last element, which is only printed once):

```
def p(lst):
    if lst:               # at least one element
        print(lst[0])     # print first element
        if len(lst) > 1:  # if it's not the last element (which is not printed twice)
            p(lst[1:])    # recursive call with the rest of the list
            print(lst[0]) # and print first element again
```

then

```
>>> p([1,2,3])  
1
2
3
2
1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That second print definitely was tripping me up. Just gotta get used to the weird ordering that recursion can create I guess.

Comment: I don't think it's weird ;-) In this case you just have to keep in mind that you can still do something *after* returning from the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Your question can be expressed in a recursion friendly manner as follows :

> Given a string "a_1.a_2...a_n" generate the string "a_1.a_2...a_n.a_{n-1}...a_1". (a_1, a_2 etc are characters. The "." is simply used as a visual delimiter.)

Lets say the string which looks like the answer you want is `S`. We know that the first and last letters of `S` would be `a_1`. So, `S` looks like `a_1.T.a_1` for some string `T`. But wait! `T` is in fact the answer we would get if the string given to us as input was `a_2.a_3...a_n`. That is the recursion.

```
def make_palindrome (input):
  if len(input) <= 1:
    return input
  return input[0] + make_palindrome(input[1:]) + input[0]

def print_palindrome (input):
  print "{}".format(make_palindrome(input))
```

Comment: Though PEP8 would mandate lowercase function names `make_palindrome` and `print_palindrome`.

Comment: @tripleee I have been camel-cased by C++.